# This widget has been unmounted, so the State no longer has a context (and should be considered defunct) in Splash Screen

Tags: android, flutter, dart, setstate, navigator

Whenever i restart my app in the keep login state, it should keep the user in the BottomNav.dart.In contrast, if I logout and restart the app, then the user will see a splash screen(The Splash()) first.But this error occur when i add the splash screen in main (Splash()) and restart the app when in a keep login state. I have no idea what causing this error happen and how can i solve it?

[image: The Error Pattern Shown in Debug Console]

> **Exception has occurred. FlutterError (This widget has been unmounted, so the State no longer has a context (and should be
> considered defunct). Consider canceling any active work during
> "dispose" or using the "mounted" getter to determine if the State is
> still active.)**

This is main()

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:recipe_collector/Authen/InfoPage.dart';
import 'package:recipe_collector/Authen/email_Login.dart';
import 'package:recipe_collector/splash_screen.dart';
import 'All Recipes/viewRecipe.dart';
import 'BottomNavigationBar.dart';
import 'package:flutter_screenutil/flutter_screenutil.dart';
import 'package:recipe_collector/globalVariable.dart' as global;
import 'Profile/Profile.dart';
import 'globalVariable.dart';

Future main() async {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //return StreamBuilder<FirebaseUser>(
    return FutureBuilder<FirebaseUser>(
        future: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser(),
        //  stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            FirebaseUser? user = snapshot.data;
            // FirebaseAuth.instance
            // .onAuthStateChanged
            //     .listen((FirebaseUser snapshot) {
            if (user != null) {
              getCurrentUser();
     }
            return MaterialApp(
              debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
              title: 'Recipes Collector ',
              initialRoute: "/",
              home: BottomNav(),
            );
          } else {
            return Splash();
          }
        });
  }
}
```

This is Splash()

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:splashscreen/splashscreen.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:liquid_swipe/liquid_swipe.dart';
import 'Authen/InfoPage.dart';

class Splash extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: SplashScreen(
        seconds: 3,
        navigateAfterSeconds:  MyliquidSwipe(),
        styleTextUnderTheLoader:  TextStyle(),
        title:  Text.rich(
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          TextSpan(
            children: [
              TextSpan(
                  text: 'Access Your Recipes Collection',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 18,
                    color: Color.fromARGB(
                      255,
                      230,
                      200,
                      160,
                    ),
                    letterSpacing: 1,
                  )),
              TextSpan(
                  text: '\nAnytime & Anywhere',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    letterSpacing: 2,
                    fontSize: 23,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                    height: 1.5,
                    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 230, 200, 160),
                  )),
              TextSpan(
                  text: '\nJust at Your Fingertip!',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      letterSpacing: 1,
                      fontSize: 18,
                      color: Color.fromARGB(255, 230, 200, 160)))
            ],
          ),
        ),
        image: Image.asset("assets/Logo.png"),
        photoSize: 150.0,
         imageBackground: AssetImage("assets/IntroPage/Create Your Own Recipe.png"),
       // backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 55, 55, 55),
        loaderColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 230, 200, 160),
        //loadingText: ,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```